# method to read data from a xsd and load it into a sql server table

Tags: sql-server-2008, xsd

I need to load one of my tables in SQL server database with some data from a xsd provided.

I have my XSD, with a block as below

```
<xsd:simpleType name="States">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:enumeration value="state1"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="state2"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="state3"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

In my table - States, I have 2 columns StateId,StateName.

I have to load the data such as state1,state2,..etc into the StateName column of the table.

Can somebody suggest which method should I use to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
-- Add the schema information and make the XML a valid XML document to parse.
SELECT @xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
        <xsd:simpleType name="Countries">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="Country1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Country2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="Country3"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:simpleType name="States">
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="state1"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="state2"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="state3"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
    </xsd:schema>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd)
SELECT 
    node.value('@value', 'nvarchar(32)')
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType[@name="States"]/xsd:restriction/xsd:enumeration') AS enum(node)
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikdor.. But if I have many nodes with '/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/xsd:enumeration' type, then how could I get data from only 1 such node. like i have the xsd- <xsd:simpleType name="Countries"> <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> <xsd:enumeration value="country1"/> <xsd:enumeration value="country2"/>  </xsd:restriction> </xsd:simpleType> <xsd:simpleType name="States"> <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> <xsd:enumeration value="state1"/> <xsd:enumeration value="state2"/> </xsd:restriction> </xsd:simpleType>  and i require to get data only from name='States' .

Comment: Ah! Updated my answer. You would add the filter on the name attribute to match "States" as `.../xsd:smpleType[@name="States"]/...`